# 9v Power for Digitial Circuit -- Parallel or Series Voltage Regulator Split

Tags: power-supply, digital-logic, voltage-regulator

I'm building a simple project that consists of a 9v LED, a 5v Gas Sensor and a 3.3v micro controller.  All the devices have low current draw, so I'm not really worried about hooking them up in parallel.

I was thinking that the 9v LED could be directly connected to a battery.  In parallel with that I would like a 5v and 3.3v voltage regulator, where both of the voltage regulators would power the other two components.

I've looked at this thread:
[Power Supply Design - Multiple Voltage Regulators](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69455/power-supply-design-multiple-voltage-regulators) but got some mixed signals regarding hooking up the voltage regulators in parallel or series, and was wondering if anyone could give me a definitive answer on best practice? Additionally, I've seen some articles that encourage bypass capacitors to help smooth out the DC signal, because I'm connecting directly to a battery I can ignore that, correct?

The LED is a MegaBrite (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10236)

The gas sensor is a MQ-3 (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8880)

and the microcontroller is an MSP430 (breadboard/launchpad version)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW0TmU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think most LED's would be happy running on 5V; but will the microcontroller talk to either LED and/or sensor? If so, don't forget level shifting 5V -> 3.3V -> 9V.

Comment: Some more details about the LED, gas sensor and uC would be nice. The gas sensors I know are power hungry, they would draw a 9V battery in no time (if the battery was able to sustain them at all). Most uC's can run on 5V.

Comment: I've updated the description above, you can see the parts now.  I'd like to power it with one power source.  If I need more batteries, or an alternative, that's fine.  I'd rather switch batteries than use multiple types of batteries though.  I doubt it would need to work more than four hours or so at a time.

Comment: The LED will run from 5.5V - any voltage above this is wasted energy unless you know that the brightness increases. According to the spec 5.5V to 9V is fine and I'd definitely use a switcher for making the power rails run more efficiently.

Comment: Is this the sort of voltage switcher you were talking about? http://www.robotshop.com/step-up-step-down-voltage-regulator-s7v7f5.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=base&utm_campaign=jos  Where I would just need one to get me to 3.3v?

Comment: Or is this what you mean? http://www.dimensionengineering.com/products/de-sw033  Switching regulators are much more expensive.  Is the main gain is less wasted power and longer battery life, I think I'd rather get the cheaper option.

Answer (score 1):

You are wasting quite a bit of power by using linear regulators to drop 9 V to 5 V and particularly to 3.3 V.  There is also no need to run the LED from 9 V.  There is no such thing as a "9 V LED".  There are some packaged devices that contain a LED and resistor so that the whole thing is intended to run from some particular volage, like 9 V, 12 V, 24 V, or whatever, but then you don't have just a LED anymore.

It would be useful to know the current requirements of the 5 V circuitry, the 3.3 V circuitry, and the LED.  I'm guessing that the sensor probably doesn't take much current.  In that case, I'd probably use a linear regulator to make 5 V as you suggest, but a switcher to make the 3.3 V from the 9 V.  The sensor runs from 5 V and everything else, including the LED, runs from 3.3 V.  That will be a lot more efficient.  Assuming this is a normal red, yellow, or green LED, it can be run from 3.3 V easily with the right resistor in series.

Comment: Well, the LED I have contains three groupings of LEDs, a 32-bit register and a controller to drive it all.  The minimum voltage of that setup is 5.5v.  I tried to get it to work with 5v, but I wasn't able to get it to behave as well.  Do you see serious concerns with going from 6v to 5v then to 3.3v?  I could do that instead. I liked the size of a 9v battery though.

Comment: Also, I plan on having the 5v sensor switched.  Do I need to have anything in place to help control extra current that may exist in the 9v and 3.3v line when the sensor is disconnected?